# Best way to scroll x and y independently for overlapping elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, inline-styles

apologies if this is a duplicate.

I have a series of nested divs as below:
-container
-row

where the container and row have an extra container each to allow scrolling without the default scrollbar showing.

I would like, when positioning the cursor over one of the row elements, to be able to both scroll the container vertically and the row horizontally. I currently have the below set up on each, but I think this is a fundamental issue with z-indexing, am I correct?

I am open to any solution, e.g. changing to some cool table that works well. I can already achieve this in pure JS I think, but it seems over the top. Thanks

A code example below:

```
    const container = document.createElement('div')
    container.id = `container__innerContainer`
    container.style = `
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ff6699;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-right: 17px;`
```

```
    const rowDisp = document.createElement('div')
    rowDisp.class = `row`
    rowDisp.id = `row-${rowNum}`
    rowDisp.style = `
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.6vh;
    font-weight: 1000;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    white-space: nowrap;`
```

I think this is enough to highlight the basic problem.

Comment: Questions that include the words "best way" are normally off-topic on SO, as "opinion-based".

Answer (score 1):

To make separate scrolls on overlapping elements, you can use the `pointer-events` property by setting `pointer-events: none;`

```
.row {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.6vh;
  font-weight: 1000;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none; /* This allows the underlying container to receive pointer events */
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ByMunajat this is useful to know, but seems to also disable the x-axis scrolling on the row. Do you know of a way to separate out the x and y axis scrolling in this way. i.e. if I hold shift and scroll, it x-scrolls the current row, but if I scroll normally, it y-scrolls the container under?